# li:hover dropdown menu on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, html-lists

How do I get li:hover to work correctly on mobile devices?

On iphone it doesn't even open, on android it doesn't close after touch :S

I want to create a custom dropdown menu and I need the javascript to get information from the li that is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>li:hover dropdown menu on mobile devices</title>

<style>
li ul{display:none}
li:hover ul{display:block}
</style>

<ul>
<li><div id=div>chose</div>
<ul>
<li id=li data-info="som data">level 2
</ul>
</ul>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('li').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('li').getAttribute('data-info');
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: in mobile device there are no hover event

Comment: It's not good practice to do like this id=div , close this with quotes like this id="div"

Comment: thanks shakti :) C-Link, in html-5 quotes arn't needed if not there are used: spaces, double and single quote marks, equal sign, greater-than sign. But thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :hover pseudo-class needs a pointing (graphical input) device, capable of distinguishing the actions pointing and selecting/activating. Usually on mobile devices with a touch interface you don't have the former, only the latter. Also some pen interfaces only allow activating, not pointing.

The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element (with some pointing device), but does not activate it. For example, a visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element. User agents not supporting interactive media do not have to support this pseudo-class. Some conforming user agents supporting interactive media may not be able to support this pseudo-class (e. g., a pen device).

[W3C: CSS 2.1: Selectors, dynamic pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

So, to answer your question: It depends on the device but likely no. And don't rely on it. With touch-screen devices quickly gaining in popularity you'll lose the entirety of pointing-only events.

Comment: Are you saying that I should not use "li dropdown menus" on mobile devices? Isn't there a solution?

Comment: can you please check this http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ and resize your browser screen and check it

Comment: I quess the solution is javscript then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get a multi-level menu working on a responsive design, or mobile version, consider this: [jQuery Responsive Menu Plugin](https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Menu) it turns a list menu into a select. You can specify the viewport for it to kick in, and the menu you'd like to use, or even combine menus.